# How to display images from a JavaScript array/object? Starting with the first Image then onclick to the next

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

Attempting to load images from my JavaScript array and display the first one the array. I then need to add a function that will allow the next image in the array to be displayed and so on till the end of the array.

```
<script>
var images = [ '/images/1.png', '/images/2.png' ];

function buildImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        document.createElement(images[i]);
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div onload="buildImages();" class="contents" id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Within the images array are paths to the images. They look like "*server/images/05-08-2014-1407249924.png*"

Comment: what are the contents of the `images` array?

Comment: Paths to images they look like http://server/images/05-08-2014-1407249924.png

Comment: Please change your sample code to something similar to that. :) Thanks!

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, the PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: This is from  (khakiout) answer and modified with a click to next picture -- http://jsfiddle.net/3E5Q9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See I did it like bellow

```
<script>
    var images = ['img/background.png','img/background1.png','img/background2.png','img/background3.png'];
    var index = 0;

    function buildImage() {
      var img = document.createElement('img')
      img.src = images[index];
      document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
    }

    function changeImage(){
      var img = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
      index++;
      index = index % images.length; // This is for if this is the last image then goto first image
      img.src = images[index];
    }
</script>

<body onload="buildImage();">
    <div class="contents" id="content"></div>
    <button onclick="changeImage()">NextImage</button>
</body>
```

I was not sure `div` has an `onload` event or not so I called `onload` of body.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/Z2745/5/)

Comment: This loads the first image perfectly, but how would I change the image to the next one in the array?

Comment: @user3889508 [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/Z2745/5/)

Comment: you can simplify changeImage and make it more dynamic:
`function changeImage(){var img = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
      img.src = images[index++%images.length];
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
// the container
var container = document.getElementById('content');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    // create the image element
    var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
    imageElement.setAttribute('src', images[i]);

    // append the element to the container
    container.appendChild(imageElement);
}
```

For more information on how to perform DOM manipulation/creation, read up on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and other resources. Those will help a lot in your development.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2745/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <body>
<img id="thepic"/>
<input type="button" id="thebutt" value="see next"/>
<script>
(function (){
        var images = ['img/background.png','img/background1.png','img/background2.png','img/background3.png'];
        var imgcnt = 1;
        function changeIt() {
          if(imgcnt<images.length){
          document.getElementById("thepic").src=images[imgcnt++];
          } else{
          console.log("done")
          }
        }

        document.getElementById("thepic").src=images[0];
        document.getElementById("thebutt").onclick=changeIt;

        })();
        </script>
</body>
```