# Show next image in Array onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on setting up images that can be clicked through with on screen arrows. Currently I have the images all showing up via a loop and an array. I have been able to set it up so that when you hover on a smallimage preview the main image will change to that image. Aka you can hover on them to see the larger version.

My array is within a mongo model: `Listings.currentimages`

My current code below works to get a small image to take over the featured image when hovered on. How would I change my code to work with on screen left/right arrows?

```
<% var imgsrc = awspath + listings.currentimages[0] %>
<img  id='mainPicture' class="image-resposive" src=<%=imgsrc%>>
<div id='allimages'>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < listings.currentimages.length; i++ ) { %>
        <div class='smallerImages'>
            <% var imgsrc = awspath + listings.currentimages[i] %>
            <img class="small" src="<%= imgsrc %>">
        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Hover feature:

```
$('.small').hover(function() {
    $('.small').removeClass('selectedImage')
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).addClass('selectedImage')
    $('#mainPicture').attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display images from a JavaScript array/object? Starting with the first Image then onclick to the next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151339/how-to-display-images-from-a-javascript-array-object-starting-with-the-first-im)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two icons (next/prev) you can define the two following event handlers in order to move right  or left:

```
$('#nextArrow').on('click', function(e) {
    var anchestor = $('.small.selectedImage').closest('.smallerImages');
    var nextImg = $('#allimages .smallerImages:first .small');
    if (anchestor.next().length != 0) {
       nextImg = anchestor.next().find('.small');
    }
    $('.small').removeClass('selectedImage');
    var src = nextImg.attr('src');
    nextImg.addClass('selectedImage');
    $('#mainPicture').attr('src', src);
})


$('#prevtArrow').on('click', function(e) {
    var anchestor = $('.small.selectedImage').closest('.smallerImages');
    var nextImg = $('#allimages .smallerImages:last .small');
    if (anchestor.prev().length != 0) {
        nextImg = anchestor.prev().find('.small');
    }
    $('.small').removeClass('selectedImage');
    var src = nextImg.attr('src');
    nextImg.addClass('selectedImage');
    $('#mainPicture').attr('src', src);
})
```

Comment: Wow incredible answer.  This works beyond perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I created some code to do what you want.  Basically, you have to keep an index of the currently display image, then use that index to show the correct image.

I created a bogus list of expanded images.  You can discard that.

```html
<script>
    var currentImage = 0;
    var maximages = 4;

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#leftarrow').click(function() {
        currentImage = currentImage - 1;
        if (currentImage < 0) {
          currentImage = 0;
        }
        updateImage();
      });

      $('#rightarrow').click(function() {
        currentImage = currentImage + 1;
        if (currentImage > maximages) {
          currentImage = maximages;
        }
        updateImage();
      });
    });

    function updateImage() {
      var kids = $('.smallerImages').children();
      var newsrc = kids.eq(currentImage).attr('src');
      
      $('#mainPicture').attr('src', newsrc);

    }
  </script>

  <img id='leftarrow' src="leftarrow.png" style="width:30px;height:200px;" />

  <img id="mainPicture" class="image-resposive" src="test1.png" />
  <span id="rightarrow">
      <img src="leftarrow.png" style="width:30px;height:200px;" />
    </span>
  <div id="allimages">
    <div class="smallerImages">
      <img class="small" src="image1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="smallerImages">
      <img class="small" src="image2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="smallerImages">
      <img class="small" src="image3.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="smallerImages">
      <img class="small" src="image4.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="smallerImages">
      <img class="small" src="image5.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
```